# print array in reverse and then add it

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Hey guys can you please help me this is the first time I am dealing with arrays and  I am tired of trying to solve this question
the task is:

I have 3 arrays and I have to first print them in order and then print them in reverse order using void functions containing a for loop.

the code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print_array(int numbers[], int length)
{
    //insert code here
}
void print_array_reversed(int numbers[], int length)
{
    //insert code here
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int data_array_1 = ( 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
    int data_array_2 = ( 2, -4, 6, -8, 10, -12, 14, -16};
    int data_array_3 = ( 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ,0};

    print_array(data_array_1, 6);
    print_array_reversed(data_array_1, 6);  

    print_array(data_array_2, 8);
    print_array_reversed(data_array_2, 8);

    print_array(data_array_3, 11);
    print_array_reversed(data_array_3, 11);

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me guys I am really struggling with this and I have not put anything in the insert code section because nothingIi have come up with has made any sense

NOTE: This isn't an assignment, i am practicing some sample questions to help me understand arrays.however Please help me as my progress has clearly hit a wall.

Comment: It could perhaps be more helpful to the question, if you added some information on what you have tried? Otherwise you've just asked for the solution.

Comment: Does your code even compile?

Comment: You don't have 3 arrays, you have 3 int variables and 3 syntax errors on assignment `(....}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the sample Code.(Print Inorder and Reverse Order)

I think, from this you will get idea how to deal with array and for loop. Keep practice.

```
#include <stdio.h>


void print_array(int numbers[], int length)
{
 printf("In order\n");
for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++)
    printf("%d ",numbers[i]);
printf("\n");

}
void print_array_reversed(int numbers[], int length)
{
 printf("Reverse order\n");
for(int i = length-1; i >=0; i --)
    printf("%d ",numbers[i]);
printf("\n");

}

 int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
int data_array_1[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
int data_array_2[] = { 2, -4, 6, -8, 10, -12, 14, -16};
int data_array_3[] = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ,0};

 print_array(data_array_1, 6);
 print_array_reversed(data_array_1, 6);

 print_array(data_array_2, 8);
 print_array_reversed(data_array_2, 8);

 print_array(data_array_3, 11);
 print_array_reversed(data_array_3, 11);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please don't answer in C++ for a question with the C tag.

Comment: Check, that's better. Strange indents but that's more cosmetic of course.

Comment: @Davidweston ok so i tried it and i am getting the output however the reverse section has an extra zero, also is there anyway i can get commas in the code? like; 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 ( Where there is no comma after 11).

Comment: See how the printf works and also see the conditional statement (if) . This things give you idea. @Mohammad.L

Comment: @Davidweston thank you David, Thanks a tonne for your help, really appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 0):

Answering entirely is just doing someone else's homework, but....

It's clear you're lost, so let's agree to resolve the question into how to handle some obvious problems from what you have, to get you moving in the right direction.

This must be changed:

```
int data_array_1 = ( 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
```

To:

```
int data_array_1[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
```

Now, you actually have an array.

Repeat with the other similar occurrences. Take care with the 3rd one, it's a duplicate name. You probably meant data_array_3.

Those changes will move you to a compilable example.

To move you from there, let's just review this one fact:

Given:

```
void print_array(int numbers[], int length)
```

As a function signature, within the function numbers[2] would be the 3rd int in the array (they start at zero). If length is 6, the last valid entry is numbers[5]. You can work backwards indexing from 5 to 0.

Let's see how that moves you forward.

Comment: this isn't my homework, i am just trying to solve these questions as practice.